# how find all hypervolume intersections quickly?

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection

Let's start with a set of axis-parallel multi-dimensional (hyper) cubes (e.g. where one of the hypercubes ranges from 5 to 9 on dimension 1, and from 2 to 4 on dimension 2). At least some of these hypercubes might overlap with each other.

What is the quickest algorithm/library for chopping up the original overlapping hypercubes into the smallest possible set of non-overlapping hypercubes? e.g.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT4sQ.jpg)

I assume this is a solved problem, I just don't know which keywords will get me there.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean with "from 5 to 9 on dimension 1, and from 2 to 4 on dimension 2".

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you can simply work one dimension at a time.

First consider the X extent of both cubes. If they are disjoint, you are done. Otherwise, consider the three subintervals covered by a single or by both cubes and slice space and get sub-cubes.

Continue with the next dimension, and so on.

Comment: Makes sense! I had been thinking of some complex recursive recombination process, this is simpler. Thanks.